# python XMLRPC + socket relay server with "kill client"

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, proxy, asyncsocket

I'm trying to make a server with Python to relay traffic from listening ports to remote hosts.  I'll call the **listening port <--> remote** host a **proxy**, which might be *localhost:54321 <--> somehost:2001*.

I need the following functionality from another thread running a XMLRPC server:

- Add a new proxy
- Kill a proxy
- Disconnect the client from a proxy listening port.

This is rather trivial to implement with threads.  Here's what I came up with:

```
import logging
import threading
import socket

class ProxyThread(threading.Thread):
   """ Thread that serves as a transport proxy """
    def __init__(self, server, client):
       super(ProxyThread, self).__init__()
       self.server  = server # (host, port)
       self.client  = client # listening socket
       self.kill_thread = threading.Event() 
       self.kill_client = threading.Event()

    def connect_server(self): 
       try: # make connection to server
           server = socket.create_connection(self.server, timeout=2)
       except Exception as e:
           return None
       return server

    def connect_client(self):
       try: # accept connection from client
           self.client.settimeout(1)
           client, saddr = self.client.accept()
       except socket.timeout:
           return None
       return client

    def run(self):
       client, server = None, None
       def close():
           if client:
               client.close()
           if server:
               server.close()
           return None, None
        while not self.kill_thread.isSet():
           if not server:
               server = self.connect_server()
               if not server:
                   time.sleep(2) # wait before retrying
                   continue
           if not client:
               client = self.connect_client()
               if not client:
                   continue
            while not (self.kill_client.isSet() or self.kill_thread.isSet()):
               # read loop 0.1 timeout to check kill_client event
               r, w, d = select.select([client, server], [], [], 0.1)
               if client in r:
                   read = client.recv(1024)
                   if not read: # disconnected
                       break
                   server.sendall(read)
               if server in r:
                   read = server.recv(1024)
                   if not read: # disconnected
                       break
                   client.sendall(read)

           # close sockets and reset
           client, server = close()
           self.kill_client.clear()
        # end of thread
       close()
       self.client.close()
```

Then from the XMLRPC thread,

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
sock.bind(("", 0))
sock.listen(1)
proxy = ProxyThread(sock, ('somehost', 2001))
proxy.start()
# later ...
proxy.kill_client.set()
```

This works but it is pretty inefficient and introduces quite a bit of latency.  Further compounding the issue is that this server will be hosting up to hundreds of concurrent proxies, and with threading this becomes a CPU hog and latency is unacceptable.

I'm looking into asynchronous frameworks such as **twisted** and **asyncio**, but I can't figure out how I would be able to add and control running proxies from another thread (the XMLRPC server).  Can anyone please help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: I figured this out in another question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384690/python-xmlrpc-socket-relay-server-with-kill-client